# How to check what rendered partial view?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I would like to render common data within these div elements.

```
<div id=element1>
    @Htm.Partial("CommonView")
    @*Other data...*@
</div>
<div id=element2>
    @Htm.Partial("CommonView")
    @*Some other data...*@
</div>
<div id=element3>
    @Htm.Partial("CommonView")
    @*More other data...*@        
</div>
```

My common view looks something like this

```
<input id="txtSomethingElse" class="input"/>
```

I can't have elements with same ids on the same page, but I need to be able to get values from `input`element. How can I implent some Razor logic that will add a prefix or sufix to `txtSomethingElse`

I would like it to be rendered like this

```
<div id=element1>
    <input id="txtSomethingElse_1" class="input"/>
</div>
<div id=element2>
    <input id="txtSomethingElse_2" class="input"/>
</div>
<div id=element3>
    <input id="txtSomethingElse_3" class="input"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: how are you getting the values? using jQuery?...if so you can skip the incrementing ID and use a selector like `$('#element1 input:first-child')` or give a specific class name `<input class="input somethingElse" />` and `$('#element1 .somethingElse')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can easily use this over load of the Html.Partial method

```
PartialExtensions.Partial Method (HtmlHelper, String, Object)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402926(v=vs.108).aspx

allowing you to pass a model to the partial view which in your case can be an int denoting an index

so you partial views changes to `<input id="txtSomethingElse_@Model.ToString()" class="input"/>`
where Model is of type `int`

and your code where you are to render this view will change to

```
<div id=element1>
    @Htm.Partial("CommonView", 1)
    @*Other data...*@
</div>
<div id=element2>
    @Htm.Partial("CommonView", 2)
    @*Some other data...*@
</div>
<div id=element3>
    @Htm.Partial("CommonView", 3)
    @*More other data...*@        
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like, say your model had an Id Property

```
<input id="txtSomethingElse@Model.Id" class="input" />
```

I'm not too good at razor, but I know the old school syntax would work

```
<input id="txtSomethingElse<%: Model.Id %>" class=input />
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do:

```
@Html.InputFor(m => m.FirstThing, new { @id = @Model.FirstThing.Id + "txtSomethingElse" })
@Html.InputFor(m => m.SecondThing, new { @id = @Model.SecondThing.Id + "txtSomethingElse" })
...
```

More readable/easier than other answers.